# Pasar multiples parametros a la API de Next.js

Tags: api, parametros, nextjs

En mi carpeta API tengo `/forecast/[coords].js`, espero poder pasarle dos datos, una `lat` y una `lon`, para que la API me devuelva el clima para los próximos días en la zona elegida.

Mi archivo `[coords].js`

```
const axios = require("axios");

const GetForecastByCoords = async (req, res) => {
  const {
    lat,
    lon,
  } = JSON.parse(req.query.coords);

  try {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://weatherbit-v1-mashape.p.rapidapi.com/forecast/daily",
      params: {
        lat: lat.toString(),
        lon: lon.toString(),
      },
      headers: {
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": "....",
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "weatherbit-v1-mashape.p.rapidapi.com",
      },
    };

    const results = axios.request(options).then(data => data);

    res.status(200).json({
      data: {
        results,
      },
      success: true,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: err.message,
      statusCode: 500,
    });
  }
};

export default GetForecastByCoords;
```

Y en el componente donde hago la llamada tengo

```
const [forecast, setForecast] = useState(null);

const forecastFetch = url => {
  fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setForecast(data));
};

useEffect(() => {    
    const coords = {
      lat: resortDetails?.geoCoordinates.lat,
      lon: resortDetails?.geoCoordinates.lon,
    };

    forecastFetch(`/api/forecast/${JSON.stringify(coords)}`);
}, []);
```

Cuando hago esta llamada, recibo en la consola algo como

> http://localhost:3000/api/forecast/%7B%22lat%22:33.807344,%22lon%22:-78.700145%7D 500 (Internal Server Error)

Si yo, en mi archivo `[coords].js` hardcodeo unas coordenadas, la API funciona correctamente. Hasta el momento habia hecho este tipo de fetchs, pero solo pasaba un parametro en `string`. Ahora que tengo que pasar dos valores, puede ser un array, o un objeto. Intenté con ambos pero siempre recibo error. Alguien sabe qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por si a alguien le pasa, la solucion fue la siguiente:

- Primero debo modificar el nombre de `[coords].js` a `[...coords].js`, de esta manera next acepta multiples parámetros. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/dynamic-api-routes#catch-all-api-routes
- En la función que hace la llamada, paso los dos valores que necesito separados por `/`

  ```
  useEffect(() => {
   forecastFetch(`/api/forecast/
     ${resortDetails?.geoCoordinates.lat}/
     ${resortDetails?.geoCoordinates.lon}`);
  }, []);
  ```
- Ahora recibo correctamente los parámetros en un array de dos posiciones. En la primera recibo `lat` y en la segunda recibo `lon`.

  ```
    const axios = require("axios");

    try {
      const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://weatherbit-v1-mashape.p.rapidapi.com/forecast/daily",
      params: {
        lat: req.query.coords[0], // solo reemplazo esto
        lon: req.query.coords[1], // y esto
      },
      headers: {
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": "....",
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "weatherbit-v1-mashape.p.rapidapi.com",
      },
    };

    const results = axios.request(options).then(data => data);
    //... el resto del codigo es igual
  ```